# ionic2: how to customize popover width?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I'm using Ionic2: I use a popover and I want to customize the size of every popover. This is the popover: [image: popover screenshot]

I want to decrease it's widt. I used this code in `variable.scss` file:

```
$popover-md-width:50%;
```

It works fine but it is applied for every popover in my application. I want to customize the width of some popover.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The [`create`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/#create) method accepts a third parameter:

`create(component, data, opts)`

Where `opts` is of type [`PopoverOptions`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/#advanced)

And one of these options, is the `cssClass` property:

```
Option      Type    Description
cssClass    string  Additional classes for custom styles, separated by spaces.
```

So you can add a custom class when creating the popover:

```
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({})
class MyPage {
  constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {}

  presentPopover(myEvent) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage, {}, {cssClass: 'my-custom-popover'});
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
  }
}
```

And then use that class to apply the custom styling.

Comment: I tried this before and used this css in the main page and popover page: .my-custom-popover{width:50%;} but no changes happened !

Comment: What happens if you add the `ion-popover.my-custom-popover { width:50%; } ` in the `app.scss` file? Since the popover component won't be rendered inside of any of those pages.

Comment: the same no changes but it caused problem with the app after click on popover button the page didn't response to any click anymore

Comment: still works in Ionic 4 (it might be the only thing =P) - thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the ts file where you wrote the popover code, set a cssClass eg.

```js
presentPopover() {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create( PopoverPage, {} , { cssClass: 'custom-popover' });
    popover.present();
}
```

Then go to your app.scss and style the popover eg.

```css
.custom-popover .popover-content{
    width: 90% !important;
    color: red;
};
```